# Extrude problem

Tags: extrude

I want to use face extrude to create a handle in a piece of pottery. I can only extrude a rectangular object with the face shape. I want to get a bulge rather than a block. What have I inadvertently switched off/ on?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). One solution would be to enable the *Subdivision modifier*. It will smooth out the rectangle, creating a bulge. 2 levels of subdivision should be enough.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'd not done. Simple fix and helped me out!